# QObjects residing inside a QThread deleted automatically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qobject

If a `QObject` is created as a class member (for example of a `QWidget`) and we try to move it to a thread it doesn't work.

If we instantiate a `QObject` not dynamically and then change its thread affinity it doesn't work.

So what needs to be done is create dynamically a `QObject`, connect all its slots and signals to the UI (for example) and then move it to a separate thread. Since it's dynamically allocated it still lives inside the memory even after we leave the function that has spawned it locally (inside the function's scope).

The problem I'm having is in understanding whether Qt automatically takes care of the `QObject` residing inside a `QThread` after we quit (`QThread::quit()` followed by waiting until the thread has finished its mergining inside the main even thread) and delete the instance of the `QThread` object.

I thing it doesn't or at least that is what I have seen while looking at the output of `valgrind`. So my question is how do we delete `QObject`s whose thread affinity has changed and no longer reside inside the main thread?

I have read about `QObject::deleteLater()` so I do believe this is the way to go. I cannot however figure out when to apply it.

Consider the following code:

```
void MyWidget::setup()
{
    thread = new QThread();
    OpenCvWorker *worker = new OpenCvWorker();
    QTimer *workerTrigger = new QTimer();
    workerTrigger->setInterval(1);

    connect(workerTrigger, SIGNAL(timeout()), worker, SLOT(receiveGrabFrame()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendSetup(int)), worker, SLOT(receiveSetup(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendToggleStream()), worker, SLOT(receiveToggleStream()));
    connect(ui->pushButtonPlay, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(receiveToggleStream()));
    connect(ui->checkBoxEnableBinaryThreshold, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), worker, SLOT(receiveEnableBinaryThreshold()));
    connect(ui->spinBoxBinaryThreshold, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), worker, SLOT(receiveBinaryThreshold(int)));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendFrame(QImage)), this, SLOT(receiveFrame(QImage)));

    workerTrigger->start();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
//    worker->deleteLater();
    workerTrigger->moveToThread(thread);
//    workerTrigger->deleteLater();

    thread->start();

    emit sendSetup(0);
}
```

Here I create an instance of a worker (inherits from `QObject`) and an instance of `QTimer`. Then I connect my UI to the worker and also the timer which is used to trigger some even inside the worker every millisecond. After that I move both the worker and the timer to the created `QThread` instance and run my separate thread.

As you can see both are dynamically allocated. However because of the scoping (can't do it in any other way since a `QObject` should not have a parent when moved to a separate thread and creating it as a class member is basically exactly that) I can't figure a way how to free the allocated memory.

Can anyone share his/her experience with this? I really don't know what to do next and I was unable to find anything useful during my search on the Internet (including SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect it to the `QThread::finished` signal, see also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#signals. Please read the Qt documentation, it is actually quite good. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details contains all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have actually read this however I have totally missed the `This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread.` :D As for the Qt documentation - when it's there, it is good (most of the time).